# How to change 'Kotlin extension' to 'View binding' make on Android-studio? please look this code

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I've been looking for how to solve this problem, but couldn't find it. Perhaps it is due to my poor coding skills. So please tell me. How to change this code statement from 'Kotlin Extension' to 'View Binding'.

```
package com.example.clother

import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_intro_pager_item.view.*

class MyPagerViewHolder(itemview: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    private val itemImage : ImageView = itemview.pager_item_image
    private val itemContent : TextView= itemview.pager_item_text
    private val itemBG : LinearLayout= itemview.pager_item_bg

    fun bindWithView(pageItem: PageItem){
        itemImage.setImageResource(pageItem.imageSrc)
        itemContent.text = pageItem.content
        itemBG.setBackgroundResource(pageItem.bgColor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to enable viewBinding in your gradle

```
    android {
```

> buildFeatures {
> viewBinding = true
> }

```
}
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

ItemBinding - the view you are using for the viewHolder, it will be automatically generated

```
class MyPagerViewHolder(private val binding: ItemBinding): 

RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

    fun bindWithView(pageItem: PageItem){
        binding.pagerItemImage.setImageResource(pageItem.imageSrc)
        binding.pagerItemText.text = pageItem.content
        .....(similarly)
    }
}
```

and in  override fun onCreateViewHolder of your adapter

you need to do something like this

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyPagerViewHolder {
    return MyPagerViewHolder(ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
  }
```